# Java: getting inner type in nested parameterized types (reflection)

Tags: java, generics, reflection, nested

Most of the documentation regarding type erasure handling in Java assumes that the use case is handling a type like `SomeType<ParamType>`.
I am trying to process method parameter for the following method:

```
public void setOtherReferenceRanges(List<ReferenceRange<T>> referenceRanges)
```

When the container class is instantiated with a type DvQuantity, this signature should become
`public void setOtherReferenceRanges(List<ReferenceRange<DvQuanitity>> referenceRanges)` in runtime.

Using reflection one can see that the `List` has an `actualTypeArgument` which is `ReferenceRange<T>`. Since reflection uses class information, I would not expect it to give me `ReferenceRange<DvQuantity>`. 
However, when I created the class containing this method, I passed the `DvQuantity` type as `T`. So the type filling in `T` should be available to Java runtime, but I could not find a way of getting it. I end up with a `TypeVariableImpl` object accessed via reflection, which does not seem to contain any useful data.

Can you think of any ways to discover this information in runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

> when I created the class containing this method

I guess you mean when you create an object of that type, for example:

```
foo = new ContainerClass<DvQuantity>();
```

In that case, because of erasure, there is no way to recover the type `DvQuantity`.

However, if you create a *class* passing a type parameter to the superclass, like this

```
class DvQuantityContainerClass extends ContainerClass<DvQuantity> {...}
...
foo = new DvQuantityContainerClass();
```

Or, shorter, an inline anonymous subclass (which looks almost like the first example but with a subtle but important difference):

```
foo = new ContainerClass<DvQuantity>(){};
```

Then you can recover the type parameter, because you recover the type parameter used to extend a superclass at runtime. Unfortunately, Java itself doesn't provide an easy way to now get the type of the `DvQuantityContainerClass.setOtherReferenceRanges` method with the `T` filled in. For that, I've written [gentyref](http://code.google.com/p/gentyref), to do advanced reflection on generic types:

```
Method m = DvQuantityContainerClass.class.getMethod("setOtherReferenceRanges", List.class);
// this will return List<ReferenceRange<DvQuanity>>, like you are lookingn for
return GenericTypeReflector.getExactParameterTypes(m, DvQuantityContainerClass.class)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It validates what I've seen so far. Unfortunately I have no power over the setup where I need to make this work. Also thanks to other responses, all of which would be useful if I had control over the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Generic type information is [erased by the compiler](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and is not available at runtime.  When I need to ensure a certain type at runtime I pass in a class argument:

```
public <T> void doSomething(T t, Class<T> c);
```

This is not always convenient or even possible, but for many cases it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

> So the type filling in T should be available to Java runtime, but I could not find a way of getting it.

Perhaps it's not entirely correct, but the way I think about it is that at runtime there is no actual class - just an object without a specific type which meets the interface of T. In other words, erasure happens not with objects, but instead with these nebulous (in the OOP world at least) type-things.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

There are ways of capturing the type information inside the class itself (T types would need a method getUnderlyingType()... or something), but that's a bad idea. If you truly need to raw type of the object, I'd reconsider using generics.